# Как узнать имя поля в JSON?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Есть файл:

```
{
    "item_gold_coin": {
        "name": "Gold Coin",
        "description": "A small disc made of lustrous metal"
    },

    "item_iron_key": {
        "name": "Iron Key",
        "description": "A heavy iron key with a simple cut"
    }
}
```

Используя библиотеку jsoncpp, я перебераю элементы (`item_*`) в файле:

```
for(auto entity : root){
            ...
}
```

И мне нужно узнать имя у `entity`. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете получить `Json::Value::Members` используя метод `Value::getMembers()`.
Пройдитесь итератором по полученному контейнеру, и у Вас будут и имена, и значения:

```
for(Json::Value::Members::const_iterator it = mem.begin(); it != mem.end(); ++it)
{
    /* *it - ключ, val[*it] - значение */
}
```

Соответственно, `val` имеет тип `Json::Value`, `Json::Value::Members mem = val.getMembers()`;